# How to avoid high CPU fan speed while running genymotion virtual device?

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, emulation

I have installed Genymotion for emulation and whenever i run a genymotion virtual device, the CPU fan starts running on high speed.
I have :

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
Bumblebee installed

How can i avoid high CPU fan speed i.e. avoid heat up due to the genymotion virtual device?

Comment: How Fabby's answer worked for you? I've the same problem with Yosemite 10.10.4 in a MacBook Pro. Thanks.

Comment: @GuilhE did not try it but i noticed that it overheats only when the emulator runs some heavy graphics game or something.

Answer (score 2):

Easy: just slow down the emulator....  Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
apt-get install cpulimit
```

then, limit the amount of CPU cycles of `genymotion`.  Again in (the same) terminal type:

```
cpulimit --exe=genymotion --limit=xx
```

where xx is the % of CPU you're willing to give it.  (I would start with 50)

Now start genymotion normally, while keeping the terminal open.

If the fan is still too loud, click on the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then type the `cpulimit` command above again lowering xx until you have a comfortable fan speed

Comment: @Sunil: did the above help?  If yes, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**